# Looking for C# HTTP Component/Class

Tags: c#

I know HTTPRequest and Response are available, but I am looking for a HTTP component/class wrapper that I can plug straight into code with less hassle.

Are there any free or paid components/classes like this?

Comment: What do you mean by HTTP Component? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: What's wrong with `HttpWebRequest`?

Answer (score 6):

It's unclear to me what exactly you are trying to accomplish. I think you want to download URLs via HTTP protocol. If that's true, I doubt you'll find anything easier to use than the built-in [`System.Net.WebClient` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) since using it is a single line of code:

```
string html = new WebClient().DownloadString(url);
byte[] data = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
```

If you need to display a Web page in a Windows Forms application, you can use the WebBrowser control.

Comment: +1 for WebClient. Best class in .NET Framework.